# Get the Bootstrap popover to stay open until cursor is moved away from it?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have this implementation that enables the user to hover over elements with the `icon-ban-circle` class, and then see a Bootstrap popover with a link:

```
## some_file.html.haml

%i.icon-ban-circle{:rel => 'popover', "data-content" => "<a href="http://www.google.com">Click here</a>".html_safe}

## some_file.js

var showError;

showError = $(".icon-ban-circle").popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover'
});
```

But once the user moves his cursor to the popover it disappears. How do I get the popover included in the `icon-ban-circle` class, so it stays open when the user tries to click the link in the popover?

Answer (score 0):

use `delay`

> delay showing and hiding the popover (ms) - does not apply to manual
>   trigger type
>
> If a number is supplied, delay is applied to both hide/show
>
> Object structure is: delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }

from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: That would get quite messy in my implementation. I am more looking for a solution where it stays open as long as the mouse hovers the popover.